# Delimitar limite de tempo para a resposta de download de request.get() [Django e Python]

Tags: python, django, request

Estou tendo problemas com o tempo de retorno de dados do servidor, quando faço uma requisição get. O servidor inicia a transmissão dos dados, mas as vezes demora muito para completar o envio (mais de 30 segundos).

Eu preciso limitar o tempo de espera do download. **Se o tempo de download superar x segundos, então cancelar a operação.**
Eu ja tentei dois caminhos:

Usar o atributo timeout do request

```
import request

r = request.get('https://www.umaURL.com', timeout=5)
```

Mas não funciona, pois o esse timeout só limita o tempo de resposta do servidor. Não serve para limitar o tempo de download.

Eu também tentei utilizar o eventlet.Timeout(), mas ele gera um erro quando eu rodo o servidor django .

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

try:
    with eventlet.Timeout(4):

        r = requests.get('https://www.umaURL.com')

except:
    pass
```

Porém, quando inicio o servidor django (python manage.py runserver) recebo o seguinte erro:

`AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'`

Alguem conhece alguma solução?

Comment: Já viu a [documentação](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) de _timeouts_ do `requests`? Você pode passar uma tupla com dois valores onde o segundo é o _timeout_ de _read_. Talvez seja isso o que você procura.

Comment: Eu também tentei passar uma tupla no timeout do request, mas não funcionou.